# editing word document using com

Tags: php, ms-word

With the following code

```
<?php
$test="C:/wamp/www/test.doc";
com_load_typelib('Word.Application');
$word = new COM("word.application");
$word->Documents->Open($test);
$word->Visible = 1;
$word->ActiveDocument->FormFields("Text1")->Result = "test";
$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
unset($word);
?>
```

I get the following problem
[image]

Line 7 is  `$word->ActiveDocument->FormFields("Text1")->Result = "test";`
What is the problem?

Comment: I think Word failed to open the document - the Word instance should be visible on the desktop.

Comment: @grahamj42 but, what could be the possible reason?

Comment: did Word load successfully ? Also, what is the error (I think something is meeing from your question) ?

Comment: I've recreated your program running PHP from the command line (Windows/XP and Word 2003) and it works, except that $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false); should be $word->ActiveDocument->Close(true); otherwise the change to the document isn't saved and one can't see whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with wamp on Windows 7. We finally solved the problem by performing the actions given in this php.net comment (although they are supposed to be useful for IIS) : http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php#90814

I copy the main part here in case the original comment disappear :

- Execute "dcomcnfg"
- Open Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
- Search for Microsoft Office Word 97-2003 Document (it will be something like this translated to your language, so take a while and search for it)
- Right-Click on it and open the properties
- Choose "Identity" tab
- Normally this is set to "the launching user". You have to change this to "the interactive user" or a admin user of your choice.
- Apply these new settings and test your COM application. It should work fine now.